# How to prevent a class from remaining active when stop() cancels the animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

I'm left stumped with an animation I got, basically I set a class on a navigation button which turns it from three pins into an x when the menu is visible.

The problem is when you spam click the button, it is possible for the `x` class to be active despite the menu being out of the screen. This is [most likely] caused by the `stop()` function since it cancels out the animation.

This is what I've tried so far:

Setting the add/remove class in a callback function of the animation, this sort of works but looks ugly because it only sets the 'X' after the animation and it also doesn't work with the `stop()`, which I need.

I originally had two seperate directives, one for handling the animation and one that sets some different values etc for the navigation elements. Then I ran one directive after the other but this gives me same effect as the current, mashed up, solution.

And this is my current attempt:

```
nav.directive('navSettings', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
          siteNav = $('#site-nav');

      siteNav.css('height', windowHeight + 'px');

      element.on('click', function() {

        var posLeft = siteNav.position().left,
            navWidth = siteNav.width();

        posLeft === -navWidth ? posLeft = 0 : posLeft = -navWidth;

        if (element.hasClass('x')) {

          element.removeClass('x');
          siteNav.stop().animate({
            left: posLeft
          });
        }
        else {

          element.addClass('x');

          siteNav.stop().animate({
            left: posLeft
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Some HTML to go along with this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <button id="nav-toggle" data-nav-settings>
      <hr ng-repeat="pin in [1, 2, 3]">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<aside id="site-nav">
  <nav class="padding narrow" ng-controller="NavCtrl"></nav>
</aside>
```

I don't what else to do really to ensure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: `spamclick` should be a tag LOL

Comment: can you explain this line: `posLeft === -navWidth ? posLeft = 0 : posLeft = -navWidth;` what are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnKiller Haha ikr. I know you never spam click but it's a bug nontheless. It checks what posLeft is, if it's the negative width of the navigation itself or if it's at 0. If it's currently out of screen (-navWidth) then animate it to 0. And vice versa.

Comment: well, shouldn't that be unnecessary? You already know if the menu is on screen or not, because you are checking this: `element.hasClass('x')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav.directive('navSettings', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
                siteNav = $('#site-nav');
                siteNav.css('height', windowHeight + 'px');
                element.on('click', function() {
                    var posLeft, navWidth = siteNav.width();
                    if (element.hasClass('x')) {
                        element.removeClass('x');
                        posLeft = -navWidth;
                    }else{
                        element.addClass('x');
                        posLeft = 0;
                    }
                    siteNav.stop().animate({
                        left: posLeft
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Removed the extra check of the left position, and moved the animation outside the `if`. Check now if spam filters work :)

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks! Let's create that spamclick tag at 1500 rep ;)